# Is there an easy way to convert a bunch of variables of one type into another type in python

Tags: python

I'm reading a csv file and assigning values from each column into variables to be processed later.  Not all values are integers in the row.  Is there a way to mass convert a bunch of variables from string into integers easily?  I don't want to type in:

```
var1 = int(var1)
```

for each variable.  Here's a snippet from my code.  Pls excuse any errors due to code sanitizing :)

```
line = line.rstrip().split('\t')
num1, str1, num2, num3, str2, num4, num5 = line[0:7]
num1 = int(num1)
num2 = int(num2)
num3 = int(num3)
num4 = int(num4)
num5 = int(num5)
```

UPDATE: Wow, thank you for all the quick replies.  Just wanted to point out, not all values are ints in the row.  There are strings mixed in too.

Comment: Why not use a list? `nums = line[0:7]` and then `nums = map(int, nums)` or `nums = [int(n) for n in nums]`?

Comment: @Carsten, thx for the quick reply.  i can't run map on it because not all the values from the line is an integer.  there are strings inter-mixed in the row from the csv file.

Comment: `nums = [int(n) if n.isdigit() else n for n in nums]` (this will fail for values like `12.5`, but succeed for true integers with only numbers)

Comment: @AdamSmith, pls make your comment an answer.  your line is what I needed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're converting a csv file, use the `csv` module!

```
import csv
from itertools import zip_longest

with open('path/to/file.csv') as inf:
    reader = csv.reader(inf, delimiter='\t')
    types = [int, str, int, int, str, int, int]
    for line in reader:
        changed_line = (type_(col) for type_,col in 
                        zip_longest(types,line, fillvalue=str))
```

`changed_line` is then `[int(col1), str(col2), int(col3), int(col4), str(col5), int(col6), int(col7)] + rest_of_columns`, and you can use it as you need!

Answer (score 5):

Yes! You can map the function which converts a value to an int to your inputs:

```
a = list('1234')
# ['1', '2', '3', '4']
b = map(int, a)
# [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Answer (score 1):

If you know the type you want for each column, you can use `zip` to match type with value:

```
line = '1\t2\tstuff\teek\n'
print [typ(val) for typ,val in 
    zip((int, int, str, str), line.strip().split('\t'))]
```

And you could wrap it in a class so that the caller doesn't need to see how the sausage is made. Here I tweaked the algorithm to use `None` as a pass through.

```
class RowConv(object):

    def __init__(self, *coltypes):
        self.coltypes = coltypes

    def __call__(self, row):
        return [typ(val) if typ else val 
            for typ,val in zip(self.coltypes, row)]

lines = ['1\t2\tstuff\teek\n']
conv = RowConv(int, int, None, str)
for line in lines:
    print conv(line.strip().split('\t'))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can either use a map as Kikohs sugested or just iterate through line as split returns a list of elements.

```
for el in line:
   el = int(el)

or 

elements = [int(el) for el in elements]
```